# Recommended maximum sessionstate timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timeout

I have a web application that currently has

```
<sessionState timeout="43829" />
```

I know this is a huge value. I want to understand the implications of having such a high timeout.

Basically the users were used to a windows client application and when this web application was built to replace the current application, they did not want a timeout. I believe this was the reason for such a high timeout vale.

I am trying to understand the pitfalls of having such a large value.

Comment: Simply...if the application requires authentication (ie a login), one implication would be security. Maintaining the shortest possible timeout window is a good security practice. You wouldn't want unauthorized access to occur because someone left their workstation for the day with the app up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Having a larger timout could increase the possibility of a [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) or other similar attack.

Since HTTP is stateless, sites often use cookies to store session identifiers that identify each users request. Each session id's secrecy must be maintained so that multiple users cannot access the same account. Once a session ID is stolen, it can be used to view another users account, even perform a fraudulent transaction.